# UTF8 encoding not working on some windows pc's

Tags: unicode

Hi I have written a Multilingal (eng and chinese) site for a client. On the pc's within their office they can't see the chinese characters. I have set a meta tag within the head section as utf8. Is there a windows setting that needs to be set ? They say they can read chinese on other sites so am assuming they already have the fonts installed.

They're using IE8 on windows (not sure if it's xp).

The strange thing is it works perfect on my old xp machinese and my windows7 gaming rig.

Comment: Is the page by any chance public where we could take a look at it and see if we see anything?

Comment: stevenportfolio.servehttp.com/. I'm using php5 and mysql on a linux box if that helps.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the encoding of the page. There were a few HTML validation errors; sometimes those can trip up certain browsers into undefined behavior: http://validator.w3.org. Maybe fix those and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: For the record, I can see the Chinese characters on that page from my English Windows XP copy.

Answer (score 2):

Just because they can see Chinese characters on other sites does not mean that they have "the fonts" installed on their machines. There is no such thing as "the fonts." Those other sites may be specifying a specific font to use, perhaps one that is not even using utf-8. Your client's machines may have that font installed, but not the one you are using.

It looks like you are specifying Arial as your display font, and the Arial font (at least, in Windows XP) does not have Chinese characters. With the multilingual pack installed, the browser tries to choose an appropriate font based on the character range. You might add the "lang" attribute to sections with Chinese characters and then specify a font-family collection for those areas that include Chinese-friendly fonts. See ["Styling using language attributes"](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang).

For the record, I can see the characters fine on Windows 7 in both Chrome and IE.

Comment: Fonts don't have a particular encoding, so you don't have to find a font that is “in UTF-8” (well, they do have encoding tables, but the OS deals with mapping tables to Unicode so you don't have to worry about it). Other than that, yes, it is a good idea to specify some common Chinese fonts, to help IE (especially 6) whose font fallback behaviour isn't great.

Comment: Yes, I could have phrased it better. What I meant was pre-Unicode fonts that simply mapped ASCII codes to glyphs of other languages. Amazingly, those are still rather prevalent. My concern was that perhaps those "other sites" were doing just that, and specifying the particular font to use. You know, the "Wingdings" phenomenon. :)

Answer (score 2):

By default, the English version of Windows XP does not have any Unicode fonts installed.  The easiest way to install some (such as MS Mincho) is like this:

**Note: You may need a Windows XP CD to change this setting!**

Go to Start, Control Panel, Classic View (if it's not set to Classic), Regional and Language Options, Languages tab.

On this page, check the box next to "Install files for East Asian language" then click OK.

It's likely a good idea to check the other checkbox at the same time.

Comment: MS Mincho is Japanese. For simplified Chinese, the fonts would be SimSun (similar to mincho) and SimHei (sans).